# Odoo v.8 I like seeing sale orders of which i am follower

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I tried Domain ---------> ('message_follower_ids', 'in', [user.partner_id.id]) but it does not work

ValueError: "name 'user' is not defined" while evaluating "[('message_partner_ids', 'in', [user.partner_id.id])]"

Comment: Do you need to add filter ? or strict domain for all ?

Comment: Hello Vipul Bhatt. No I don't need to add filter.

Comment: Please post you solution in an answer, not in the question, also remove SOLUTION from title for more information see [tour]

Comment: Ok, Thanks Petter.

Answer (score 0):

It gives error because user is not defined , if you want to get current login user us `self.env.user` instead of just `user`

```
('message_follower_ids', 'in', [self.env.user.partner_id.id])
```

Comment: Thanks Heroic, but if i write that in domain, i get the same error:  name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, not code. I just added the domain attribute in the window action. Setting > Technical > Action > Window Actions > Filter Domain                                                   - Object: sale.order                                                                                                        - View: sale.order.tree

Comment: SOLUTION: [('message_is_follower','=',1)] in domain. It's work. Thanks!!